# How to Data Bind ListBox in Silverlight for Windows Phone7

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Need some help in ListBox DataBindg in Silverlight for Windows Phone. The code as follows:

1) On Page Load Event :

Note :  Pictures is a collection of picture, PicNames is collection of names of pictures.

```
var ml = new MediaLibrary();
var ChkPics = ml.Pictures;
var PicNames = from p in ChkPics
               where p.Name.Contains("s")
               select p;
```

2) Static Class

```
public static class PhotoNames
{
    private static List<string> m_Photoname = new List<string>();

    public static List<string> PhotoFileNames
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Photoname;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Photoname = value;
        }
    }
}
```

After getting all the photo filenames in the PicNames in this way:

On Page Load Event :

```
var ml = new MediaLibrary();
var ChkPics = ml.Pictures;
var PicNames = from p in ChkPics
               where p.Name.Contains("s")
               select p;

foreach (var pic in PicNames)
{  
    PhotoNames.PhotoFileNames.Add(pic.Name);
}
```

How do I bind a ListBox to this static class and show all the data in `TextBlock` inside ListBox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ml.Pictures has all the info you need (name and picture). Why do you need the static class?

You could do the following:

```
var ml = new MediaLibrary();
listBox.ItemSource = ml.Pictures.Where(picture => picture.Name.Contains("s"));
```

And in your XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"></local:ImageConverter>
...
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="35"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Picture, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"></Image>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The template shows both the picture's name and the picture itself in a thumbnail, if you don't need the picture, use DisplayMemberPath instead.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" DisplayMemberpath="Name">
</ListBox>


/// <summary>
/// Converts an image path to the associated image.
/// </summary>
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter implementation
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string imagePath = (string)value;
        Uri Uri = new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.Relative);
        return new BitmapImage(Uri);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works partially as no Picture display. base on this var ml = new MediaLibrary(); 
listBox.ItemSource = ml.Pictures.Where(picture => picture.Name.Contains("s"));

Comment: The Picture not showing. base the Where statement. I have made changes on the XAML : Picture to picture or Picture.

Comment: The Picture not showing. base the Where statement. I have made changes on the XAML : Picture to picture or Picture.

Comment: Sorry. accidentally press the Enter btton.  What  I need to do if I dont need pic and How to use the Path ?

Comment: Thank you. This has answered my question. It will be nice if you can help me how to get the picture displayed. I tried many ways but still cant get picture (Thumbnail) to display. I just got the photo filenames.

Comment: Use a converter in this case (I've updated the XAML and source code)